# Move a file in from input feild to a folder using only jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to move a file I select from input to a folder "uploads" without using php. I just want to use JQuery or JS.
I have this HTML code:

```
<input id="attachmentFile" name="attachmentFile" type="file">
<button type="button" id="btnUpload" name="btnUpload">UploadAttachment</button>
```

The JQuery Function is:

```
$('#btnUpload').on('click', function() {
var file = $("#attachmentFile")[0].files[0];
files.Move("/uploads");
});
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: You don’t need to use PHP but if you want to transfer files to the server you’ll need some server side system to handle it

Comment: server side system ? can you elaborate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a server side system. If you would want to stay in JS, Node.js (on the server side!!!) would give you great possibilities. It provides a core module for Filesystem operations and a Core HTTP Module for handling Requests. Sorry for my English, but I hope that will give you a direction.

Comment: So i cannot do it without server side system ?

Comment: As far as I know no, there is no way... . :-( . Sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your help ^_^